# Underscore as fulltext search word boundaries in MariaDB 10

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb

Let's assume that a table **node** has a varchar column **description** with fulltext index in MariaDb 10.

The query

```
 select description from node where match(description) against('night');
```

will match description values like

```
Night-and-day
What-a-wonderful-night
What a wonderful night
```

but will not match

```
What_a_wonderful_night
```

Now my question: it seems that space ( ) and hyphen (-) are considered to be word boundaries, but underscore (_) not. Is there a way by configuration or inside the query to make underscore be a word boundary as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the macro true_word_char() in ha_innobase.cc:

```
-#define true_word_char(c, ch) ((c) & (_MY_U | _MY_L | _MY_NMR) || (ch) == '_')
+#define true_word_char(c, ch) ((c) & (_MY_U | _MY_L | _MY_NMR))
```

and rebuild MariaDB.

Comment: Please note that adding an additional character set or collation will not work, since the check for underscore is hard coded in macro true_word_char.